# HBase is not launching zookeeper on 1 node out of 3

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to set up HBase on a small cluster as a learning exercise.

The machines are 17, 47 and 50. 47 is supposed to be the master, with 17 as a backup master and 17 and 50 as region servers. They all have zookeeper set up correctly, which I've verified with the zkCli: I can create and access nodes from all 3 machines.

However, when I try to launch HBase (from 47) with: `hbase-start.sh`, I get these logs:

```
47: running zookeeper, logging to /home/ubuntu/hbase-2.5.5/bin/../logs/hbase-ubuntu-zookeeper-47.out
50: running zookeeper, logging to /home/ubuntu/hbase-2.5.5/bin/../logs/hbase-ubuntu-zookeeper-50.out
17: /home/ubuntu/hbase-2.5.5/bin/hbase-daemon.sh: line 92: kill: (186871) - No such process
17:
17: ers
17:     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.HQuorumPeer.writeMyID(HQuorumPeer.java:154)
17:     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.HQuorumPeer.main(HQuorumPeer.java:67)
```

(Trying to read the log file on 17 yields no further information, it contains precisely what is listed here, including the 'ers' line.)

When I then launch the hbase shell and run `status` I see:

`1 active master, 1 backup masters, 2 servers, 40 dead, 0.0000 average load`
(The number of dead servers rises every time I start and stop so I'm guessing it's just the number of servers that I've stopped.)

With jps, I see HMaster and HRegionServer on 17, HMaster and HQuorumPeer on 47, HQuorumPeer and HRegionServer on 50. So only Zookeeper (as HQuorumPeer) is absent on 17. The rest seems fine. (Except that I can't create tables on HBase, with the error message `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PleaseHoldException: Master is initializing` which I hope is caused by the problem with Zookeeper.)

I'm using HBase 2.5.5 and Zookeeper 3.9.0.

Here are my Hbase conf files:
hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>./tmp</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.unsafe.stream.capability.enforce</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.wal.provider</name>
    <value>filesystem</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://47:9000/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>47,17,50</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/ubuntu/zookeeper-data</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

hbase-env.sh

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

backup-masters

```
17
```

regionservers

```
17
50
```

What can I do to fix this?

I'm editing the conf to try and get more logs.